# Keynote delay is longer than 0 seconds

Tags: keynote, animation

In keynote I want to seamlessly animate a couple slides together with magic move.

However, this seems impossible because even setting the delay to '0' keynote still noticeably delays almost a whole second inbetween animations.

How do I make keynote not delay?